# iphone- Can't remove objects from array

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsmutablearray

My app is nearly finished but I am having a problem, I can not remove objects from an
array I made.

This is a sample of my code:

```
-(void) TheGame{

  squares = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h" ,@"i" ,@"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"q", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"aa", @"bb", @"cc",@"dd", @"ee", @"ff", @"gg", @"hh", @"ii", @"jj", @"kk", @"ll", @"mm", @"nn", @"oo", @"pp", @"qq",@"rr", @"ss", @"tt", nil] retain];

  s=40;
  turn=1;

  while(s >= 1)
    if (turn == 1){
      //Check for players move
      //Here I added some if statement, and for every one I added 
      //[squares removeObject: @"b"]; X can be any object of the array.
      turn = 0;
      s = s - 1;
    }

  if (turn == 0){

    //Here the computer should find an object from the array randomly. I used
    //randomN = [squares objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [squares count]];
    //to choose the random object.

    //After choosing, the item should be removed from the array, also using
    //[squares removeObject: @"X"]; X can be any object of the array.

    turn = 1;
    s = s - 1;
  }
}
```

The problem is, for example, if the player chooses the object "b" from the array, then

```
[squares removeObject: @"b"];
```

should trigger.

when it comes to the computer random move, there is a chance that it picks the same object
which was already removed from the array, which is @"b" in my example.

So that means, the items are not being removed from the array when

```
[squares removeObject: @"X"];
```

triggers.

Any one got a solutions for this problem ?

Please,, I need your help.

======= SOLVED ========

I tried to use your answers but could not manage to solve the problem..

The solution was so simple :p .. Just moved the array to "viewDidLoad" method.

Thanks guys for your help, so sorry but I can't accept answers as non worked for me.
I appreciate you effort.

Comment: You've been a member for 3 months, and asked 7 questions. Your 6 other questions have all received answers, and one has even gotten 4 answers. I think you should consider reading the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq - and accept some answers to your previous questions. Once you've done that, people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Hi, but when I try to rate the answer, I get a message saying that I have to get 15 rep in order to rate.

Comment: I am so sorry, did not know about that,, I have just done it. accepted the useful answers I got from the users

Comment: And now you have enough reputation to vote :)

Answer (score 2):

You might try using indexOfObject: then removeObjectAtIndex: to remove an item from the array.

I suspect that if you debug, indexOfObject might give you a result of NSNotFound (very large number) which means that for some reason it would think the array did not hold the string you are passing in.  Very probably something in the string you are passing in to remove an entry from the array is not matching with the equivalent entry in the array.

Comment: Thanks for answering, by using indexOfObject, does it mean I am assigning a location for the object in the array? for example, "a" is at 1, "b" at 2. Is that right ?

Comment: It returns the index where it thinks the object is - so like you said, "a" would be 1, "b" 2.  If instead of 1 or 2 you get back a very large number, that is the NSNotFound constant which means the string you are asking the location about is not the same as the string the array is holding, and that would also be why "removeObject" would not work, because it thought there was no object to remove.

Comment: 1 more question before I try it,, If there are 2 objects in the array, "a" atIndex 0, and "b" atIndex 1, when I removeObjectAtIndex 0 which is "a". Will "b" move to index 0, or it will stick with 1 ?? because if it moves, the method would net be useful for my app.

Comment: It will move, but that is why you just always call "indexOfObject:" first, because it will always give you the current location of the object in that array.  So if you call indexOfObject:@"b" after you have removed "a", it will return 0 and you remove the object at that index.  But mainly I was thinking to try this not as a permanent technique (because removeObject should work) but instead as a debugging step to tell you - are the strings I am passing to removeObject: really in the array or are they somehow different?

Comment: Solved
I tried to use your answers but could not manage to solve the problem..

The solution was so simple :p .. Just moved the array to "viewDidLoad" method.

Thanks guys for your help, so sorry but I can't accept answers as non worked for me. I appreciate you effort.

Answer (score 1):

I would use NSMutableDictionary instead of Array that way you can have a direct access for adding/removing etc...

Comment: Solved I tried to use your answers but could not manage to solve the problem.. The solution was so simple :p .. Just moved the array to "viewDidLoad" method. Thanks guys for your help, so sorry but I can't accept answers as non worked for me. I appreciate you effort

Answer (score 1):

Your original question is unclear, but I think you're having problems with the age-old issue of pointer referencing.

The following is a typical example of two strings that are the same, yet are not *exactly* the same:

```
if (@"bears" == @"bears")
{

}
```

the above only compares pointers, not strings. Saying something like `[squares removeObject:@"b"];` is incorrect, because you're allocating a new string (b) and then saying to your Array; "remove the object referenced by this pointer", when what you've been expecting is "remove the object that contains a b in it" (which is not how Arrays work).

tl;dr, use a Dictionary.

Comment: How can I implement my array "squares" as an NSDictionary? I have been looking for a tutorial, I have found that there are Values and keys, So I am not sure how to make it. After making the dictionary, can I use "randomN = [squares objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [squares count]]" to pick a random object? Thank you very much.

Comment: Solved I tried to use your answers but could not manage to solve the problem.. The solution was so simple :p .. Just moved the array to "viewDidLoad" method. Thanks guys for your help, so sorry but I can't accept answers as non worked for me. I appreciate you effort